# Hiding Custom Action for Just one document library

Tags: 2007, development, document-library, custom-actions, redirect

I have a custom action deployed for a site collection, now if I want to hide it for a custom document library is it possible.

Also this is what I am doing actually, can you think a better way of doing it ?

I created a Custom Action that will run some custom code for me after a page redirect to a custom application page (I tried attaching a control assembly to my code but it failed miserably maybe because its not supported by "GroupId="ActionsMenu" ) anyway now my custom page redirect does some calculations on "Page_Load" method and then redirects user back to list page (it all happens so quickly that user doesn't realized which is what I wanted).

but Now I want to display a message box after redirect, but dunno how I can do this, any guidance would be appreciated.